# ImageView Bitmaps are incorrectly oriented

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, orientation

I've seen several questions regarding this topic, but none that address my problem.

I dynamically create ImageViews and allow the user to take/add photos of items for an inventory. The following code exists to generate the Bitmap and populate the ImageView:

```
protected void addPhotosToView(ArrayList<String> uris) {
    for (String uriString : uris) {
        try {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriString);
            File imageFile = new File(uri.getPath());
            int orientation = resolveBitmapOrientation(imageFile);
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), uri);
            bitmap = applyOrientation(bitmap, orientation);

            ImageView image = new ImageView(ItemActivity.this);

            int h = 100; // height in pixels
            int w = 100; // width in pixels    
            Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, h, w, true);

            image.setImageBitmap(scaled);

            LinearLayout photoLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.itemPhotoLayout);
            photoLayout.addView(image);

            addClickListener(image, uri);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But once the image is added or taken, some images appear with the wrong orientation. Some of the photos stored in the phone in portrait are displayed in portrait, while others appear to be in landscape. Landscape photos are equally arbitrary.

This does not appear to be happening on all devices (the device that I'm seeing this on is a Samsung S4)

As you can see in the code, I have tried getting/applying orientation changes using Exif tags, but I'm always getting 0 for the orientation with this device and have not seen any answers for questions that ask for a solution when orientation is always 0.

I'm looking to ship this software soon and need some sort of workaround or solution, so I'm willing to accept some other way of going from Uris/strings to a dynamic, horizontally scrollable list of properly oriented images if this can't be resolved any other way.

Comment: looks like the exif orientation problem I faced it too I solved it by decoding the bitmap and checking for exif orientation . if the exif data orientation is present then the bitmap is rotated accordingly

Comment: I believe @IllegalArgument is correct. But please post the code of `resolveBitmapOrientation()` and `applyOrientation()` (judging only from their names, it would seem you're already taking this into account -- maybe they are failing for some cases?).

Answer (score 1):

you need to decode the bitmap that's all try [this tutorial](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/android-take-photo-camera-gallery-code-sample/) you can download the source.
that application dose exactly what you want maybe it will help you i hope because it worked fine with my application

Comment: I'm having some difficulty getting this to work as expected. Any time I try to create a new instance of BitmapFactory.options, I'm getting a NPE on the argless constructor.

Comment: i did not encouter that problem so look at this code,it is easier to run just follow it step by step.  http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/e14021/capture-image-from-camera-and-selecting-image-from-gallery-o/

Comment: This code also relies on BitmapFactory.options, so I'm unable to follow any of it because of the NPE.

I'm not inclined to believe that it's any of my code, either, as there are no parameters and the object is constructed wholly on its own.

Answer (score -1):

Please use this method to show/decode your bitmap. It is taken from another SO post I cant remember which and is modified for my use. This method returns bitmap according to the exif orientation data if present on the image:

```
public Bitmap decodeFile(String path) {// you can provide file path here
    int orientation;
    try {
        if (path == null) {
            return null;
        }
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
        // final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 20;
        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 0;
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                    || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
            scale++;
        }
        // decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o2);
        Bitmap bitmap = bm;
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(path);
        orientation = exif
                .getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);
        Matrix m = new Matrix();
        if ((orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180)) {
            m.postRotate(180);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(),
                    bm.getHeight(), m, true);
            photo(bitmap, path);
            return bitmap;
        } else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) {
            m.postRotate(90);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(),
                    bm.getHeight(), m, true);
            photo(bitmap, path);
            return bitmap;
        } else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {
            m.postRotate(270);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(),
                    bm.getHeight(), m, true);
            photo(bitmap, path);
            return bitmap;
        }
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: As I state in my other comment, I'm having some trouble with BitmapFactory.options - any attempts to construct it are resulting a NPE for the variable that references it when used. Any ideas?

Comment: in that case some codes and logcat output would be helpful the above code is tested and works for me so just give it a try